# Calculate the gradient of a linear scalar field

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

I am trying to calculate the following gradient

$$\nabla_{\mathbf{X}} \left( \mathbf{a}^{T} \mathbf{X} \mathbf{a} \right)$$

where I am using the convention that $\mathbf{a}$ is a column vector. I am wondering what the steps are to extract the solution from the matrix cookbook, which is:

$$\nabla_{\mathbf{X}} \left( \mathbf{a}^{T} \mathbf{X} \mathbf{a} \right) = \mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{a}^{T}$$

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2807864/derivative-of-the-trace-of-the-product-of-a-matrix-and-its-transpose/2809102#2809102

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut thanks for the heads up! But then how do you use $\frac{\partial y}{\partial X}$ to estimate $\Delta y$ for a $\Delta X$? This won't be done with usual matrix operations? While it is trivial in our case that $\Delta y = a^T \cdot \Delta X \cdot a$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Read *all* of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2807864/derivative-of-the-trace-of-the-product-of-a-matrix-and-its-transpose/2809102#2809102 You just have to compute $\Delta y=\mathrm{tr}(A^T\Delta X)$, where $A=dy/dX$ and $\mathrm{tr}$ is the [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)).

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I am trying to understand he reason for this derivation actually!

Comment: @JoseRamon What didn't you understand about [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3109914/339790)?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo the details the swapping but I think I am getting close from the rest answers.

Comment: @JoseRamon Which swapping? Do you mean the [cyclic property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Cyclic_property) of the trace?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes exactly why is not $y^{T}x$ and it is $yx^{T}$. Can you elaborate more about the connection of the cyclic property of the trace with the result?

Comment: @JoseRamon Because of the [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product). Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2189946/339790).

Comment: Yes so it is another way of answering, but I find @Jean-ClaudeArbaut answer more intuitive.

Comment: One more question if I have a MxN matrix lets say A, then the derivative $\partial (cA)/ \partial A$ where c is a scalar, is $M \times N$ c, right? Or $N \times M$

Comment: @JoseRamon Be careful. $A \mapsto c A$ is no longer a scalar field. The output is a matrix, not a real number. The derivative is a $4$-dimensional matrix.

Comment: So the derivation of a 2d matrix with a 2d matrix gives a 4d matrix as a result?

Comment: @JoseRamon Yes, because you're differentiating each entry of the output matrix with respect to the input matrix. You can also use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2189946/339790) to find each of these derivatives.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo in this case $y^{T}Ax$ it is a scalar right?

Comment: @JoseRamon Yes.

Comment: Great! I will try to figure out the solution with trace that is bit unfamiliar with me as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2807864/derivative-of-the-trace-of-the-product-of-a-matrix-and-its-transpose/2809102#2809102) for the basics and the notation.

The derivative of the scalar function $f(X)$ with respect to $X$, where $X$ is a matrix, is the matrix $A$ with $A_{i,j}=\dfrac{df(X)}{dX_{i,j}}$.

And here,

$$f(X)=a^TXa=\sum_{i,j} X_{i,j}a_ia_j$$

So that

$$\dfrac{df(X)}{dX_{i,j}}=a_ia_j$$

And finally

$$A=\frac{df(X)}{dX}=aa^T$$

Comment: I have some basic linear algebra questions, Firstly, if a dimensions is 5x1 and X dimension is 5x5, is it that the result of $a^{T}Xa$ will be a scalar? Secondly, why I can write the first expression $\Sigma_{i,j}X_{i,j}a_{i}a_{j}$? Then, I cannot understand since there is not a swap in indexes of i and j why I have the swap for the transpose.

Comment: @JoseRamon Yes, the result is a scalar. And it is critical to understand it to well to know what is happening!

Comment: I guess this is because it is scalar ($\Sigma_{i,j}X_{i,j}a_{i}a_{j}$), right? But then I do no see the transpose.

Comment: Yes I got the scalar part, so in the example for the partial derivative $\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{X})}{\partial X_{ij}} = a_{i}a_{j}$. Then I compose my result with all these partial derivatives. Then the final matrix has size NxN. But why transpose?

Comment: @JoseRamon It's an [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product): the $(i,j)$ element of the matrix is the prodyct $a_ia_j$. It's exactly the same as $aa^T$ (check for yourself, the matrix product $aa^T$ is trivial here).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut yes I think I am getting closer :)

Comment: @JoseRamon Regarding your first question: $b^TXa=\sum_i b_i (Xa)_i=\sum_i b_i(\sum_j X_{i,j}a_j)=\sum_{i,j} X_{i,j}b_ia_j$ (where $X$ is a matrix and $a,b$ are vectors, with compatible dimensions). Note that $Xa$ is a vector, and for two vectors $u,v$, $u^Tv$ is their scalar product.

Comment: In this case is not scalar right? It is the outer product of b and a.

Comment: The product $aa^T$ is not a scalar, but a matrix. However the product $a^Ta$ is a scalar. Just write the matrix product, and consider vectors to be *column* vectors (a matrix with one column). And ins $b^TXa$, you have the scalar product of $b$ and $Xa$, which are both vectors. Hence the function you differentiate is a scalar function of the matrix $X$.

Comment: $(df/dX)(X) = a \cdot a^T$ is a linear form that associates to a matrix $u$ a scalar. How do you obtain the scalar knowing the matrices $a \cdot a^T$ and $u$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2807864/derivative-of-the-trace-of-the-product-of-a-matrix-and-its-transpose/2809102#2809102, where I wrote the detailed derivation. $df/dX$ is indeed a linear form, but it's written in compact form as a matrix, by convention: instead of writing a vector with $np$ entries, it's more compact to write a $n\times p$ matrix. See also the Wikipedia link above and the layout convention part (there are two competing conventions).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thanks. I understand now! I don't know what you think, but this seems **very complex** to use such results. Moreover, in term of practical stuff, do you know if those conventions are used in usual linear programming packages?

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{array}{l|rcl}
f : & M_n(\mathbb R) & \longrightarrow & \mathbb R\\
    & X & \longmapsto & a^T X a \end{array}$$

is a linear map.

**Critical is to understand what the domain and codomain of $f$ are in order to understand what $f$ is as a function.**

Hence its Fréchet derivative at each point is equal to itself: $f^\prime(X).u =a^T u a$.

Following a detailed and interesting discussion with [Jean-Claude Arbaut](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/43608/jean-claude-arbaut) (see the comments!), we can rewrite

$$f^\prime(X).u =a^T u a = \mathrm{tr}(a^T u a) = \mathrm{tr}(u \cdot (a \cdot a^T))= \mathrm{tr}((a \cdot a^T) \cdot u) = \mathrm{tr}(A \cdot u)$$

where $A = a \cdot a^T$ is defined as the [matrix calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Derivatives_with_matrices) derivative of $f$ with respect to $X$. This is in fact what is meant by

$$\nabla_{\mathbf{X}} \left( \mathbf{a}^{T} \mathbf{X} \mathbf{a} \right) = \frac{\partial\left( \mathbf{a}^{T} \mathbf{X} \mathbf{a} \right)}{\partial \mathbf{X}}=\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{a}^{T}$$ in the [Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf).